# Redefine "[<-" in S3 class in R

Tags: r

I have a S3 class that contains two matrices. I want to use `[` and `]` functions to replace the element in both matrices.

For example:

```
twoMat <- function(MatA,MatB)
{
  x <- list(MatA = MatA, MatB = MatB)
  class(x) <- "twoMat"
  x
}
```

Suppose A is my S3 class with matrices B and C as members.

I want to type this:

```
A = twoMat(B,C)
A[A$B<3] <- NA
```

And get this for the members:

```
B[A$B<3] <- NA
C[A$B<3] <- NA
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a reproducible example. It is quite unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like you want to define the `[<-` operator for your twoMat class, so that you can reassign these values to NA based on your index values in []. You will need to use the standard assignment operator for this `<-` not `=`.